# displaying within decimal range in python

Tags: python

I am reading the wrox Beginning Python book. In chapter 2, the example states

```
>>> print "$.03f" & 30.00123
$30.001
```

However this does not explain the behavior of the command. Why use .03 when .3 and .003 etc have the same behavior in the shell? Furthermore, it does not explain what happends when I just use 3

```
>>> print "%.03f" % (2.34567891)
2.346
>>> print "%.003f" % (2.34567891)
2.346
>>> print "%.0003f" % (2.34567891)
2.346
>>> print "%.3f" % (2.34567891)
2.346
>>> print "%3f" % (2.34567891)
2.345679
```

I tried searching but couldnt get results as I dont know what the relevant keywords are.

Comment: The `%` operator is being phased out, slowly. I'd start using `format`: `print '{:.4}'.format(2.34567891)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `0` in `'%.03f'` does nothing. This is equivalent to `'%.3f'`.

As for the second question, what does `'%3f'` do, it simply specifies the length for the whole number, exactly as it would in `'%3s'`. It becomes clear if you make it longer:

```
>>> '%10f' % 2.3
'  2.300000'
>>> len(_)
10
>>>
```

Comment: And the default is 6 for `%f`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature known as *string formatting* or *string interpolation*.  Its documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).  It works very similarly to the C function [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)'s format strings.

Comment: I don't think he's asking so much what string interpolation is, as why the it's formatted with '.03' vs '.3' which yield the same output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "%.3f", "%.03f", and "%0.003f" have any difference among them, the number after the decimal-point is processed as a number by printf-family, so 3 == 03 == 003. However, "%.0f" will truncate the decimal places. Also, "%.f" is different from "%f".

But the representation of "03" isn't useless in printf-family, it pads zero in front of the number to be printed if necessary,

```
>>> print "%5d" % (123)
  123
>>> print "%05d" % (123)
00123
>>> print "%5d" % (123456)
123456
```

"%3f" in your example does same thing as "%5d" in mine. It prints a at-least-three-number-long string. So,

```
>>> print "%3f" % (2.34567891)
2.345679
>>> print "%3.f" % (2.34567891)
  2
>>> print "%3.1f" % (2.34567891)
2.3
>>> print "%3.2f" % (2.34567891)
2.35
>>> print "%3.3f" % (2.34567891)
2.346
>>> print "%30f" % (2.34567891)
                      2.345679
>>> print "%30.8f" % (2.34567891)
                    2.34567891
>>> print "%30.9f" % (2.34567891)
                   2.345678910
```

Don't forget if the decimal point is omitted in the format string, the default decimal place is 6.